# How to run cypress open with electron

Tags: electron, cypress

I am having issues with cy.visit hanging in electron only, but chrome is fine. There are no errors in the console with cypress run, so would like to run `cypress open` with electron, but not sure how. `cypress open --browser electron` or `node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress open --browser node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron` doesn't work.

I have tried `cypress run --headed` but cypress run doesn't allow you to stop the test mid way through and investigate what is wrong. Pausing the test closes the window.

Comment: Were you able to use Electron with cypress open?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the docs about the [open command](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-open), the browser flag is used only to specify a path to a custom browser to be added to the list of available browsers in Cypress. Electron being the default browser bundled with Cypress, you don't have to specify it when launching the UI. You can choose any browser you need on the UI before launching a test suite (see screenshoot).

[image]